# Create parent record with child many by django form

Tags: django, python-3.x

In my django project I have code as below:

```
forms.py

class addOrderForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Orders
        fields = [ 'shipvia', 'customer', 'employee', 'orderdate', 'freight', 'shipname', 'shipaddress', 'shipcity', 'shipregion', 'shippostalcode', 'shipcountry' ]


views.py

def addOrder(request):
    OrderDetailsFormSet = inlineformset_factory(Orders,
            OrderDetails,
            fields=('product', 'unitprice', 'quantity' , 'discount'),
            extra=3)
    order=Orders()
    if request.method == 'POST':
        f = addOrderForm(request.POST, instance=order)
        fs = OrderDetailsFormSet(request.POST,instance=order)
        if fs.is_valid() and f.is_valid():
            f.save()
            fs.save()
            return HttpResponse('success')
    else:
        f  = addOrderForm(instance=order)
        fs = OrderDetailsFormSet(instance=order)
    return render(request, 'orders/addOrder.html', context = {'fs': fs,'f':f,'order':order})



orders/addOrder.html

{% block body %}

<form action="/orders/addOrder/" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <div class="row">
        {{ fs.management_form }}
    <table>
        {% for form in fs.forms %}
        {% for field in form %}
                <tr><th>{{field.label_tag}}</th><td>{{field}}{{field.errors}}</td></tr>
                {% endfor %}
    {% endfor %}
    </table>
</div>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
<script type="text/javascript">
            $(function () {
            $('#datetimepicker1').datetimepicker({
        inline: true,
            sideBySide: true,
            format: 'YYYY-MM-DD',
                                });
                                });
        </script>
{% endblock %}
```

There are two tables in the database

ORDERS table:

```
orderid        | smallint              | not null default nextval('orders_orderid_seq'::regclass)
customerid     | bpchar                | 
employeeid     | smallint              | 
orderdate      | date                  | 
requireddate   | date                  | 
shippeddate    | date                  | 
shipvia        | smallint              | 
freight        | real                  | 
shipname       | character varying(40) | 
shipaddress    | character varying(60) | 
shipcity       | character varying(15) | 
shipregion     | character varying(15) | 
shippostalcode | character varying(10) | 
shipcountry    | character varying(15) | 
Indexes:
"pk_orders" PRIMARY KEY, btree (orderid)
Foreign-key constraints:
"fk_orders_customers" FOREIGN KEY (customerid) REFERENCES customers(customerid)
"fk_orders_employees" FOREIGN KEY (employeeid) REFERENCES employees(employeeid)
"fk_orders_shippers" FOREIGN KEY (shipvia) REFERENCES shippers(shipperid)
Referenced by:
TABLE "order_details" CONSTRAINT "fk_order_details_orders" FOREIGN KEY (orderid) REFERENCES orders(orderid)
```

ORDER_DETAILS table:

```
orderid       | smallint | not null
productid     | smallint | not null
unitprice     | real     | not null
quantity      | smallint | not null
discount      | real     | not null
orderdetailid | integer  | not null default nextval('orderdetails_orderdetailid_seq'::regclass)
Indexes:
"pk_order_details" PRIMARY KEY, btree (orderdetailid)
"uk_order_details" UNIQUE CONSTRAINT, btree (orderid, productid)
Foreign-key constraints:
"fk_order_details_orders" FOREIGN KEY (orderid) REFERENCES orders(orderid)
"fk_order_details_products" FOREIGN KEY (productid) REFERENCES products(productid)
```

At current state with above django code I'm able to add new Orders record (but only with orderid column populated, all others in row are NULLs) and complete Order_details row (which is taken from the form). 
My question is how can I provide remaining columns data for Orders table, not only auto orderid?

Answer (score 0):

Finally I found it, just call f in the template as below and Orders form field will appear and will be added during database commit:

orders/addOrder.html

```
{% block body %}
    <form action="/orders/addOrder/" method="post">

{% csrf_token %}
<div class="row">
    {{ f }}  <!- new line is HERE -->
    {{ fs.management_form }}
<table>
```